# how many network adapters does an evil twin attack require

Tags: wifi, wireless

what is the difference between performing an evil twin attack with 2 wireless adapters or with just on or is it even possible to perform this attack with just one adapter? i am using Kali Linux

Comment: How many children do you need at once to have twins? What the difference in numbers between "single child" and "twins"? Among your twins, how many of your twins do you need to be evil to have an "evil twin"?

Answer (score 2):

Evil twin is an attack whereby you mimick a legitimate wireless network and try to get victims to associate to yours rather than to the legitimate one.

Conceptually, to execute the attack, all you need is one adapter. Now if you want to route traffic over another wireless network (or simply use the Internet...), you'll need another adapter to connect to that network.

Comment: i want to make a phising page appear when the client try to use a website to make a client enter there password for penetration testing does that require another adapter?

Comment: The fact you are asking that question reveals that you are lacking a significant portion of knowledge required to execute an evil twin attack. I suggest you go research the basics, then test your attacks on your own lab.

Comment: i am gonna test this attack with airgeddon on my router so its automated but i am a noobie and i really wanna know if i should buy 2 adapters cause some say 2 and some say 1

Comment: *Some say 1 and some say 2*, and that's exactly what you'd get from here, too. Ultimately you need to think for yourself, because it's you alone who knows the exact plan for the attack.

Comment: You can run multiple virtual interfaces on one wiphy, and each can be in a different mode. So with one physical interface, you could have 2 separate virtual interfaces, one acting as an AP and the other as a client, if supported by the interface

Comment: @nonope2454 "some say 2 and some say 1" -> you could provide more details, e.g., why do some say 2, some say 1. What reasons do they provide? And what do you think of the reasons?